# "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable" Laravel on Azure

Tags: laravel, azure, iis, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I have deployed my laravel app on azure web app
when trying to access long URL I get this error

`The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`

Also, I edit my web.config and added these options

```
<system.webServer>
     <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" />
    </requestFiltering>
</system.webServer>
```

But still not working

Comment: Could you please tell me what the url you have used to access the lavel application which hosted on the azure web app?

Comment: The issue solved
You can check the correct answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue has been solved by adding this section to my public/web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxQueryString="32768"/>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be your config for laravel

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/laravel-tasks/blob/master/public/web.config

also please note that the laravel index.php file is under public so you need to add public to the URL

Comment: I replaced my web.config with this file but still the same error

Comment: did you add /public to the url too ?

Comment: should I change this     <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />  to           <action type="Rewrite" url="/public/index.php" />  even I have this web.config in /public dir not /

Comment: It should work, check this URL for better explanation https://gist.github.com/jatubio/80dfc57fc18546706ec0