# Running Azure Functions on Azure giving error: The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I am new to Azure Functions and I am trying to follow the tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-java
to create a basic HTTP Trigger Function using Visual Studio code and to deploy the same to Azure.

I have created the function and executed it locally and has deployed the Java HTTP Trigger Function to Azure as well, but while trying to execute the function in Azure I am getting the following error:

[image: Function_error]

Can anyone please help me in resolving the above error.

Thanks & regards,
Preethi H R

Comment: After deploying to azure, you can run your http function in azure portal iitself, no need to use postman, try over there once

Comment: Hi, I have also tried executing the function on Azure also. I was getting the same error on Azure portal as well so I have tried executing it on postman.

Answer (score 0):

***We have also tried to reproduced the issue ,But its working fine after following the below steps and configuration.***

*After Creating java function with http trigger and deployed to Azure checked the following if same or not which you have created in your local with version details*.

[image]

Including that please *check the configuration file if any of the `localsettings` is missed because when we deploy azure function to azure from local(VS/VSC) need to configure the `localsettings` manually in the configuration section*.

**For example:-**

[image]

*Tested successfully via postman in our environment*:-

[image]

Please refer the below links for the similar issues:-

- *Similar* **SO THREAD**| [***The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable" Laravel on Azure***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59544461/the-resource-you-are-looking-for-has-been-removed-had-its-name-changed-or-is) .
- **GitHub**| [***Deployment error - Error: The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed***](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azureappservice/issues/395) .